# The Lie algebra of vector fields and the action of the associated Lie group

Tags: differential-geometry, lie-groups, lie-algebras, smooth-manifolds

Let $M$ be a smooth manifold and let $\mathfrak g$ be  the Lie algebra of smooth vector fields on $M$. Suppose that $\mathfrak g$ is finite dimensional.

Let $G$ be a connected Lie group such that $\mathfrak g$ be its Lie algebra.

Are the following statements correct:

1. There is an induced group action of $G$ on $X$ if the vector fields in $\mathfrak g$ are integrable.
2. If $G$ acts on $X$ transitively then the vector fields in $\mathfrak g$ are integrable.

Comment: What does $f$-related mean?

Comment: sorry,, I mixed it up with something else.. I changed it now

Comment: The Lie algebra of vector fields on a manifold of positive dinension is never finite dimensional.

Comment: If M is the real line, and G is the one dimensional lie algebra spanned by a constant nonzero vector field, you can take G to be $S^1$, and it does not have an action of M.

Comment: Actually, I should have modified my question. I can ask this question: If $X$ is a complex manifold and $G$ is a real Lie group acts on $X$ by holomorphic transformations. If $\frak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and if $\hat {\mathfrak g} :=\mathfrak g+i\mathfrak g$ let $\hat G$ be a Lie group associated to $\hat{\mathfrak g}$. When $\hat G$ has an action on $X$?